# How to decrease animation duration in AwesomeWM?

Tags: lua, window-managers, awesome-wm

I am running a Linux Mint 20 laptop with AwesomeWM 4.3 with ChrisTitusTech's material-awesome. It is my first time using any WM but the experience was great. The only issue is that the animation, like opening and closing windows, moving workspaces, and widget pop-ups, takes so long and I cannot find the config file responsible for it either in `~/.config/awesome/` or `/usr/share/awesome`. I would prefer to just reduce the animation time or, if not possible, disable at least some animations

Comment: AwesomeWM does not do any animations. Are you using some composite manager (xcompmgr, compiz, compton, ...)?

Comment: Thank you for the insight I have finally solved it.